# C перевод строки(char) в число(int)

Tags: c, char

Переменная `not_num` содержит строку из трех символов-цифр, например `"528"`. Необходимо получить из этой строки соответствующее ему число и присвоить его переменной `num`. Вывести на экран результат выражения num – 10. (Подсказка: строка — это массив символов, следовательно, вы можете извлекать символы цифр по их индексам; при вычислении числа первый символ массива, преобразованный в число, будет означать количество сотен, второй — десятков, а третий — единиц.)

Comment: Для любого символа `c` в диапазоне `0..9` числовое значение может быть получено как `c - '0'`. Можно воспользоваться этим.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема? Почему просто не воспользоваться функцией `strtoul`?

Comment: @AnT, исходя из *подсказки в тексте вопроса* проблема в отсутствии представления о кодировках символов (впрочем, семестр уже явно закончился)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char not_num` - может, вы все же имели в виду `char*not_num`?

Посмотррите на функции типа `atoi` или `strtol`.

P.S. Первое уточнение (интересно, сколько их еще будет? :))

```
num = 0;
char* s = not_num;
while(*s)
{
    num = num*10 + (*s++ - '0');
}
```

Comment: Вот задание: Переменная not_num содержит строку из трех символов-цифр, например "528". Необходимо получить из этой строки соответствующее ему число и присвоить его переменной num.  Вывести на экран результат выражения num – 10.  (Подсказка: строка — это массив символов, следовательно, вы можете извлекать символы цифр по их индексам; при вычислении числа первый символ массива,  преобразованный в число, будет означать количество сотен,  второй — десятков, а третий — единиц.)

Comment: И там нету нечего по поводу сторонних функции

Comment: А что в задании написали вы? :) Плохое ТЗ - и результат ХЗ...

Comment: Окей, щас исправлю)

Comment: @Harry Код не читабельный, но гениальный! :)

Comment: Все круто, но задание дано на том етапе когда еще не изучались циклы. Я их знаю но хотелось бы сделать точно.

Comment: @Biggy, цикл всегда можно раскрыть как последовательность инструкций

Comment: Окей, спасибо!!

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а что тут нечитабельно? *s++ это классика имхо. А вот скобки можно и убрать)

Comment: @pavel Скобки - это намек для большего понимания...

Comment: @Harry я ждал тут ответа `100*a[0]+10*a[1]+a[2]-5328` )

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, `man indent`?

Comment: @biggy: Если "там нету нечего по поводу сторонних функции", значит функции стандартной библиотеки *можно и нужно* использовать. Если бы их нельзя было использовать - такой запрет должен быть четко оговорен.

Comment: @pavel, `100**a` выглядит прикольнее ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
int num;
num = (not_num[0] - '0') * 100 + (not_num[1] - '0') * 10 + (not_num[2] - '0') 
printf("%d\n", num - 10);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
long num = strtol(not_num, NULL, 10);
printf("%ld\n", num - 10);
```

Вот и все.